# Get all media with type "image" from Instagram API

Tags: python, django, api, instagram

I am trying to get only images of a user from Instagram API like this:

```
shop_recent_items, next_ = instagram_api.user_recent_media(
                user_id=obj.insta_user_id,
                count=33)
```

this returns both images and videos. I tried even this:

```
shop_recent_items, next_ = instagram_api.user_recent_media(
                user_id=obj.insta_user_id,
                type='image'
                count=33)
```

again I get both image and video type media.

**How do I get only images?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the official [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent), it says it may return a mix of both image and video types. So you cannot possibly say you only want images. Instead, once you retrieve the info, extract images.

So once you get the JSON data, using a for loop, you can find all the images. Sample code:

```
for media in shop_recent_items:
    try:
        print media['images']
    except KeyEror:
        continue
```

If you could show me exact response and contents of `shop_recent_items`, I will edit this sample code accordingly.

Comment: I did this: if media.type != "images": continue. This is in a for loop.

Comment: yup, that should work too. If my answer helped you, then please accept it.